# i can't make a contact group on iPhone, how can i solve that?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

hi i'm studying a iOS programming, but i have a trouble

i want to make a contact group, and add my address book.

but the problem is my code works on simulator, but iPhone doesn't.

i don't know why is that, here's my code

```
-(void) createAGroupInContact:(NSString *)aGroupName
{
   CFErrorRef error = NULL;
   ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
   ABRecordRef group = ABGroupCreate();

   if(ABRecordSetValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty, aGroupName, &error)) {
      NSLog(@"setValue ok"); //set value is succeed on iPhone and simulator both.
   else {
      NSLog(@"setValue fail");
   }

   if(ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, group, &error)) {
      // when i run my code on simulator, group is saved.
      NSLog(@"group save ok");
   }
   else {
      // but when i run my code on iPhone, group doesn't save
      NSLog(@"group save fail");
      NSLog(@"error = %@", error); // it printed error = (null)
   }

   if(ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error)) {
      NSLog(@"save ok");
   }
   else {
      NSLog(@"save fail");
   }
   CFRelease(group);
   CFRelease(addressBook);
}
```

i try to solve this problem myself, but can't.

why this code success on simulator successfully, but why doesn't on iPhone?

is anywhere do i fix it? how can i fix it? please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some AddressBook sources do not support group creation. Do you sync with MS Exchange or anything similar on your iPhone?